# tabular content inside a div with several columns (column-count)

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui

How can I let tabular content oveflow into a column next to it? Neither a table nor a div-table-imitation does the wanted behaviour. Anybody an idea?

```
<style>
    .columns
    {
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 10px; 
    -webkit-column-rule: 0px dotted black;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-gap: 10px;  
    -moz-column-rule: 0px dotted black;
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 10px; 
    column-rule: 0px dotted black;
    }
</style>


<div class="columns">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>This</td>
            <td>Stuff</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>should</td>
            <td>flow</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>into</td>
            <td>the</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>next</td>
            <td>column...</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>..</td>
            <td>..</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Or do I have to write the rows somehow seperately and adjust their cell's width by jquery for instance?

Comment: Would you please tell us what you really want to do?! Could you provide a picture of what you want?! I can't understand what you mean!!!

Comment: Is it really so difficult to understand? Imagine there is text inside a div of my class .columns,  this text would be seperated within 3 vertical columns. like in a newspaper, the text from the first column would continue in the second column, when it has reached the bottom. there has not to be a specified height, css distributes the text eqully to the columns. now i want ro have the same effect when using a table inside this div. the rows should be be treated like "text-lines" and jump into the next column(of the div).

Comment: What an insulting language!!!!!! First, learn how to talk politely. Then, come back here and we will help you !!!

Comment: sorry, this was not meant insulting at all, but yes it could have sounded like this. it was an emphasis on the 'really', not the 'understand', so it was a real question.